# Woocommerce/Wordpress Email Multiple Attachments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have two functions:

```
public function send_order_attach_itemone($attachments,$order_info) {
 // Code here
}
public function send_order_attach_itemtwo($attachments,$order_info) {
 // Code here
}
```

How can I attach both items? This is the call:

```
add_filter('send_order_email',array($this,'send_order_attach_itemone'),10,3);
```

I can get it to attach one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many filters as you want (This works with all WordPress filters).

```
add_filter('send_order_email',array($this,'send_order_attach_itemone'),10,3);
add_filter('send_order_email',array($this,'send_order_attach_itemtwo'),10,3);
```

Please note that the last parameter of add_filter ("3" in your code) is the number of arguments the callback function expects but your functions only accept 2 parameters `($attachments,$order_info)`. So you should change either the filter call or the functions.